# Elasticsearch - filter conditions order

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization, filter

Can you tell me please if the conditions in Elasticsearch filter are evaluated in the order as they are in the request json or if Elasticsearch will make some optimization in it?
I have a query like:

```
{
    "sort": {
        "publishDate": "desc"
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "publishDate": {
                            "lte": "2018-10-26",
                            "gt": "2018-08-31"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "ico": [
                            31322832,
                            34444444
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and I think the optimal order of filters when evaluating is terms first and range next. So what happens in Elasticsearch? Filters will be evaluated in request order or will be optimized? Also if somebody knows how is it in Elasticsearch 2?

Thanks.

Comment: Check [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) and [profile api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html)